# jquery.datePicker questions

Tags: jquery, css, calendar

With an div and iframe I generate an popup with jQuery:

```
<div id="popup_add_onderhoud" class="popup_block">
<iframe src="add_onderhoud.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="425" height="260">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to use an jQuery calendar script found on: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePicker.html

Works nice but the calendat generate in my script is much larger then the one on the original site, it seems I can't change this. Any ideas?

Also the posistion is not right, I have tried to change it with http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerPosition.html but no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('.date_pick').datePicker();
    ('#bl').dpSetPosition($.dpConst.POS_BOTTOM, $.dpConst.POS_LEFT);
});
</script>

<input type="text" class="date_pick" id="bl" name="datum_volgende" size="10" value="<?php echo $datum_volgende ?>" />
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the padding, or maybe better yet, the font size for each `td` in the calendar, the total width of it will shrink.

I believe you want to change this:

```
table.jCalendar td {
    ...
}
```

Assuming you're using the stylesheet from the first site you linked to (it looks the same).

It is definitely just a CSS issue though.